# Building Android APK which includes another file that will be ran

Tags: android

I am trying to build a app that after it is installed, will drop another binary that I will execute from within the app. It is basically the command `ifconfig` but my own version that has some other additions.

Ideally when the single APK file is moved to the device and installed, I would like for the `ifconfig` file to be dropped in the apps local folder where it will then be used with `ProcessBuilder` to execute.

Is this something that can be done with Android? The other option would be to download the file but I prefer to have it included with the APK.

Comment: Bear in mind that this goes against the distribution rules for the Play Store (and possibly other app distribution channels).

Answer (score 0):

You can't quite get that, but you can get the same effect.  You can put the file in as an asset, and write the file to the filesystem on first boot of your application.  Just check if its already on the filesystem, and if not read it in from assets and write it to the filesystem.

I do question why you're going this route though. Why are you using a C binary rather than writing it in Java/Kotlin?  Or using a C library linked via the NDK?  Running it via ProcessBuilder is a definite code smell.

Comment: It is a binary that I got from termux. Termux has a lot of functionality and I just need one of the binaries it uses but want to use it with my app.